# Jquery collection plugin for symfony not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

Since I've put together all of my Javascript and jQuery file, the Jquery plugin collection for Symfony didn't work. I don't know why but when I click on the add button, nothing happen ...

Here is my jQuery code :

```
    var indexAdd = 0
    var collectionToAdd ='';
    jQuery('.my-selector').collection({
        allow_up: false,
        allow_add: true,
        allow_down: false,
        after_remove: function(collection, element) {
            indexAdd--;
            var count = 0;
            jQuery(collection).children().each(function(){
                if(jQuery(this).is('div')){
                    count++;
                }
            })
            if(count > 1){
                jQuery(element).find("a.collection-add.collection-action").eq(indexAdd-1).parent().show();
            }
            if(count == 0){
                jQuery(collection).find('a.collection-action.collection-rescue-add').css('display','unset');
            }
        },
        after_add: function(collection, element) {
            jQuery(element).css('margin-top','50px');
            indexAdd++;
            collectionToAdd = '';
            collectionToAdd = collection;
            jQuery('#modalCollection .modal-body .col-6').empty()
            var nomCollection = jQuery(jQuery(collection).parent()).parent().find('label').eq(0).text()
            if(jQuery('#modalCollection .modal-body .col-6 h1').length == 0){
                jQuery('#modalCollection .modal-body .col-6').append('<h1>'+nomCollection+'</h1>')
            }
            jQuery('#modalCollection .modal-body .col-6').append('<div class="detach"></div>')
            jQuery('#modalCollection').modal('show');
            jQuery(jQuery(element).detach()).appendTo('#modalCollection .modal-body .detach')

            jQuery(element).parent().children("div").each(function(){
                jQuery(this).children("label").css('display','none')
            })
            jQuery(element).find('label').each(function(event){
                if(jQuery(this).text().indexOf('label') > 0){
                    jQuery(this).hide();
                }
            })
            newCollection = jQuery(element).parent().find("div:last").parent()
            jQuery(newCollection).find("div").wrap('<td></td>')
            jQuery(newCollection).find("div").each(function(){
                jQuery(this).find("td").wrapAll(('<tr></tr>'))
                if(jQuery(this).find("label")){
                    label = jQuery(this).find("label").attr("for")
                    if(typeof label !== 'undefined'){
                        label = (label.substring(0, String(label).indexOf('-'))).substring(label.lastIndexOf("_")+1)
                        jQuery(this).find("label").html(label)
                    }
                }
            })

            jQuery(element).find('td').each(function(){
                jQuery(this).find('div').attr("class","md-form")
                jQuery(this).find('div').each(function(){
                    if(jQuery(this).find('input').attr('type') == 'file'){
                        jQuery(this).find('label').hide();
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    })
```

Here is the form view : [formView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTnrh.jpg)

That's how I create my CollectionType :

```
    $builder->add($key, CollectionType::class, array(
                            'entry_type' => DynamicFormType::class,
                            'entry_options' => array('data' => $arrayOfFieldType),
                            'allow_add' => true,
                            'allow_delete' => true,
                            'prototype' => true,
                            'attr' => array(
                                'class' => 'my-selector',
                        ),));
```

When i clicked on the add button (in blue) nothing happen.
If someone have an idea, will be great to know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want ? add a new field when you click on your button ?

Comment: Yes, i ommited to say that this worked since I've put together all of my JS file, i had no problem before ...

Comment: ok, so first, i don't know why you did all taht JS code, dynamic SF form is like that : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

second thing, edit your post with all the elements we need to help you ...

Comment: Yeah I know, i read those documentation but in my case it's a bit more complicated, I don't generate this form with an entity store in my Database. This form is generated with an XSD, then i build all of my field with this XSD. But here it's not the question because this one worked really well 2 hours ago.. I think something wrong happened when I concatenating my JS file (don't know if concatenating mean something).

Comment: again , edit your post with all the elements we need to help you ! if we don't know all the problem, how can we help you ? show how you put them together, what you v done, if you got error in your console...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly to the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I just add to add a my-selector class that was deleted i dont know how but everything is working now.